# Twilio 11200 HTTP Retrieval Failure — What does this mean?

Tags: node.js, express, twilio

I've seen a few questions on Twilio's HTTP retrieval failure error.

After quickly implementing a Node.js messaging server using Express, I began to consistently hit this error. It occasionally lags my text message responses by 10-20 seconds and shows up in the debugger.

I'm wondering if I might be missing something obvious here. Since I'm using Twilio's example code it seems like this should work out of the box.

My code is as follows:

```
app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {

  const data = req.body
  const message = data.Body
  const sender = data.From

  console.log('We\'ve received a text...')
  console.log('Sender: ', sender)
  console.log('Message: ', message)

  const responses = [
    'Message #1.',
    'Message #2.',
    'Message #3.',
    'Message #4.'
  ]

  client.sendMessage({

      to: '+11231231234', // Any number Twilio can deliver to
      from: '+11234564567', // A number you bought from Twilio and can use for outbound communication
      body: responses[ Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) ] // body of the SMS message

  }, function(err, responseData) { //this function is executed when a response is received from Twilio

      if (!err) { // "err" is an error received during the request, if any

          console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+14506667788"
          console.log(responseData.body); // outputs "Printing some stuff."

      }

  });

})
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and/or how to resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

By looking at your code, it seems you're responding to a text message by setting up the webhook on Twilio console.

When you use webhooks, Twilio expects your page to return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), and in case your page doesn't return it, you will get intermittent 1200 retrieval errors. Your page doesn't currently return anything.

The good news, is that you can simplify that code a lot by using TwiML instead and returning something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Sms from="+14105551234" to="+14105556789">The king stay the king.</Sms>
</Response>
```

You can use the NodeJS library to generate that TwiML, or create the TwiML manually as I did above. An example of generating TwiML in NodeJS would be as follows:

```
app.post('/message', function (req, res) {
  var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  resp.message('some message you wanna add');
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type':'text/xml'
  });
  res.end(resp.toString());
});
```

Hope this helps you